# HTML5 geolocation error handling not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, firefox, geolocation

There is an HTML5 geolocation sample code on w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_map

You can find very similar codes on Google's website and other:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

When I run these codes in Chrome it does what it's supposed to do. However when I run them in my Firefox (version 25.0.1), it works well when I allow 'sharing location', but doesn't do anything when I don't allow 'sharing location'. It just doesn't run the tasks in handleNoGeolocation(...). For example for the w3schools demo (link above), in Firefox when I click on "Not Now" in the 'share location' box that appears, it doesn't do what it's supposed to do which is displaying `User denied the request for Geolocation.` (it works fine in Chrome). What's wrong with the code and how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: make sure you are running the page from a webserver not a local file

Comment: @ajayel I can't ask the user's of my website to install FF 30.0. Isn't there any other solution? The problem occurs when I run the page from a webserver and not a local file.